# How Do I Disable AIRPLANE MODE tablet supports 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, airplane-mode, android-settings

I have to **disable** `AIRPLANE MODE` and `DATE TIME SETTINGS` in my app, for that i used these **intent filters** but `none` of them `works` for me

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.settings.DATE_SETTINGS" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But earlier i successfully **disabled** `Settings` by using below `intent-filter`

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What does it mean to disable air plane mode ? You want to disable it programatically ? You want to prevent the user from disabling it while using your app ?

Comment: May I ask you why you want to disable airplane mode? Furthermore, why would you want to disable core system functionality?

Comment: @StephaneMathis No I want to prevent the user from enabling it while using my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for version 4.2 and up you are not able to control the Airplane mode programmatically.

You are able to do so only if the user has a rooted device.

As written in the API DOC:

**"Some device settings defined by Settings.System are now `read-only`. If your app attempts to write changes to settings defined in Settings.System that have moved to `Settings.Global`, the write operation will silently fail when running on `Android 4.2` and higher.
Even if your value for `android:targetSdkVersion` and `android:minSdkVersion` is lower than `17`, your app is not able to modify the settings that have moved to `Settings.Global` when running on `Android 4.2` and higher."**

Comment: Is there any way to turn on/off airplane mode programmatically in android 4.4.2 ?

Comment: Like stated above - As of version 4.2 and up - There is no way unless your device is rooted

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: Don't do that.**

Think what happens if user couldn't enable airplane mode though if they want/should.
Important system settings cannot allowed to change from your app.

I recommend:

1. Check airplane mode is disabled or not
2. If enabled, prompt "this app is not work on airplane mode. open system settings app?" with "yes/cancel" dialog
3. Close your app and/or open system settings app

**EDIT:**
it looks like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void checkAirplaneMode() {
    int mode;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Log.v(TAG, "work with new api.");
        mode = Settings.Global.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "work with old api.");
        mode = Settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "airplane mode: " + mode);

    if(mode == 1 /* airplane mode is on */) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Sorry!")
                .setMessage("This app doesn't work with Airplane mode.\n"
                        + "Please disable Airplane mode.\n")
                .setPositiveButton("Open Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS));
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Close app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

here's some point.

- Check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to use `Settings.Global` for newer devices. Airplane mode is moved to here.
- If mode == 1, device is in airplane mode.
- Open airplane mode setting Activity by
  `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS));`

Comment: I tried this solution: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/01/airplane-mode-onoff-in-android-with.html and i am able to turn on/off airplane mode on android version 4.0.4 but getting error while using on android 4.4.2, so can you show me the way of doing this ?