# Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTING not working in android 4.4.2

Tags: android

I am trying to open airplane mode setting page from within my application using intent:new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS). This seems to work for android version 6.0.1 and 5.1.1, but not for 4.x. Any pointers on what can be done in this case?

Comment: It may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356953/how-do-i-disable-airplane-mode-tablet-supports-4-4-2

Comment: Are you trying something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on